# Unity Editor Randomly Freezing on play mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, freeze

Unity editor freezes when I move a character (doesn't matter which), but it doesn't always happen, I still couldn't identify the exact trigger that makes it freeze, but it always happens after I click the mouse on a tile to move the character.
Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
public class TacticsMove : MonoBehaviour {

public LayerMask tileLayer;

private bool moving = false;
private bool jumping = false;
private bool jumpingUp = false;
private bool movingEdge = false;
private bool fallingDown = false;

public float moveSpeed = 2;
public float jumpVelocity = 4.5f;

private Vector3 velocity = new Vector3();
private Vector3 heading = new Vector3();
private Vector3 jumpTarget;

private Unit unit;

private Queue<Tile> path;
private List<Tile> walkableTiles;


void Start(){
    unit = GetComponent<Unit>();
}

void Update(){
    if(moving){
        Walk();
    } else if(this.gameObject == TurnManager.GetActiveUnit()) {
        CheckMouse();
    }
}

private void CheckMouse(){
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){
        Debug.Log("Check Mouse");
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        Debug.Log("1");
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, tileLayer)){
            Debug.Log("2");
            if(hit.collider.tag == "Tile") {
                Debug.Log("3");
                Tile t = hit.collider.GetComponent<Tile>();
                if(t.moveable){
                    Debug.Log("4");
                    MoveTo(t);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Debug.Log("8");
        }
    }
    Debug.Log("5");
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel")){
        Debug.Log("6");
        MovingCleanUp();
    }
    Debug.Log("7");
}

public void PrepareMovement(){
    Debug.Log("PrepareMovement");
    unit.GetCurrentTile().current = true;
    int range = (int)(unit.GetCurrentAP() / unit.apToMove.Value);
    walkableTiles = unit.GetCurrentTile().TilesInRange(unit.jumpHeight.Value, false, range);
    foreach(Tile tile in walkableTiles){
        tile.moveable = true;
    }
}

public void MoveTo(Tile target){
    Debug.Log("MoveTo");
    SetStateToMoving(true);
    unit.GetCurrentTile().current = false;
    path = CreatePath(target);
    int apCost = (int)(path.Count * unit.apToMove.Value);
    unit.ReduceAP(apCost);
}

private void Walk(){
    Debug.Log("Walk");
    if (path.Count>0){
        Tile t = path.Peek();
        Vector3 target = t.transform.position;
        // target.y += (halfHeight  + t.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y)* transform.localScale.y;
        target.y += t.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;

        if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target) >= 0.05f) {
            // jumping = transform.position.y != target.y; //correto
            SetStateToJumping(transform.position.y != target.y);
            if(jumping){
                Jump(target);
            } else{
                CalculateHeading(target);
                SetHorizontalVelocity();
            }

            transform.forward = heading;
            transform.position += velocity * Time.deltaTime;

        } else{
            //Tile center reached
            transform.position = target;
            path.Dequeue();
        }

    } else {
        MovingCleanUp();
    }
}

private Queue<Tile> CreatePath(Tile target){
    Debug.Log("CreatePath");
    Queue<Tile> path = new Queue<Tile>();
    Tile closest = unit.GetCurrentTile();
    while(closest != target){
        foreach(Tile t in closest.FindNeighbors(unit.jumpHeight.Value, false)){
            if(Vector3.Distance(t.transform.position, target.transform.position) < Vector3.Distance(closest.transform.position, target.transform.position)){
                closest = t;
            }
        }
        path.Enqueue(closest);
    }
    return path;
}
```

}

Here is the whole script: https://pastebin.com/CD0xR120

I have no Idea how to debug this since there is no error messages, it just freezes as this GIF shows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPW4r.jpg

Here is what happens in the code:

1. Player clicks the button Move and the button calls the method PrepareMovement
2. On the update method, the function CheckMouse is checking if the user clicked on a moveable tile (the ones that are blue)
3. if the player clicks on a moveable tile, the function MoveTo is called and creates a path for the character to walk and then sets the character to the state moving = true
4. the method update is always checking if it the character's state is moving, if it is the function Walk is called and it makes the character walk towards its destination.

Everything was working fine, this is the first script that I wrote for this game, then everything worked, and I was working on other things and everything was going well, until out of nowhere it started suddenly freezing.

Here are some things that I tried doing and didn't solve the issue:

- Updating the unity version from 2018 to 2019
- Starting a project from scratch and adding just the minimal to make the character walk
- Removing from the Character all other scripts except the one that makes him walk
- Removing the walking animation

I have no idea what else to do, any help is much appreciated even if it is some way I can get more info on this issue (perhaps a log file that I'm not aware of). Everything I found here, on Unity's forum orn google seems to point towards an infinite loop, which I don't think is my case...

Thanks for your help and attention!

**UPDATES**: code updated with debug messages in every method, here is the console output when it freezes:

```
[11:38:53] 5                    (78)
[11:38:53] 7                    (78)
[11:38:52] PrepareMovement      (1)
[11:38:52] Check Mouse          (1)
[11:38:52] 1                    (1)
[11:38:52] 8                    (1)
```

(I would have taken a screenshot, but turns out you can't if the window is not responding...)
so, from that console output I can only conclude that the line making it freeze is this:

```
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, tileLayer)){
```

but I have no idea how a raycast can freeze unity...

Comment: Place a breakpoint in your while loop when you try to get your path. Unity freezes if you are stuck in an endless loop

Comment: I guess you are using `FindNeighbors` from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-get-surrounding-tiles-or-game-objects.468513/)? Did you make sure to ignore the `Tile` itself from the returned list? Otherwise you might end up always getting the current Tile as `closest`. Also make sure the `CircleCollider` is big enough because otherwise you don't find any neighbour tiles

Comment: @Immorality I placed a debug message in the method just before starting the loop, and when it freezes it don't even gets to the method with the loop, in fact it seems to crash on a Raycast that is being cast from the camera to the click point, please check the updates I made to the question

Comment: @derHugo no, I rolled my own FindNeighbors which has a similar logic to that, but it ignores itself, it seems to me that the problem is raycasting from the camera to the tile clicked, if you could check the updated question and give me any insights it would be great!